# SORT parameter in DataFrame.append in python

Tags: python

I have 2 programs, something like this:

1st program

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()

d1={ 12:12,13:13,67:34}

df=df.append(d1,ignore_index=True)

d2={'JIGNESH':{'roll':12,'marks':[12,34]} ,
'AURA':{'roll':134,'marks':[67,67]}
}

df=df.append(d2,ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

2nd program

```
dfe=pd.DataFrame()

d1={ 12:12,13:13,67:34}

df2=pd.DataFrame(d1,index=[0])

dfe=dfe.append(df2)

df3=pd.DataFrame(
{'JIGNESH': {'roll': 12, 'marks': [12, 34]},
'AURA': {'roll': 134, 'marks': [67, 67]}})

dfe=dfe.append(df3)

print(dfe)
```

In case of 1st code I get a o/p . In case of 2nd code I get a o/p as well as warning saying that-

> C:\Users\ILESH\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py:107: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
>     result = result.union(other)

Now my question is why am I  getting this error only in 2nd program and not in 1st?

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet of code, your index is only numeric:

```
df.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)
```

In your second piece of code, your index mixes numeric and string types:

```
dfe.index
Index([0, 'marks', 'roll'], dtype='object')
```

In the second one, it doesn't know how to sort a string vs an int, so it throws you the warning, similar to when you try to run the below:

```
lst=[0,4,5,'a','b',8]
lst.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: As per the python docs , sort will sort the columns not the index

Comment: This is true if you are actually invoking `sort`, but in this case you are doing a join. In the first function, you call `ignore_index=True`, but in the second you pass it the index.  When you do the join, it is trying to reconcile the index values, as seen in the warning, `pandas\core\indexes\api.py`. Additionally, the columns are the same between the two dataframes, but the indices are different, and you asked why you got the error on one and not the other

Comment: so is sorting bcoz of columns or index ??

Comment: Sir can u plzz explain it in more betterr way .

Comment: The index of `dfe` is numeric. The index of `df3` is strings. When you try to append `df3` to `dfe`, it tries to sort the index while it appends, to get the dataframe in the right order. It works, but it warns you that it can't put it in the right order, because it can't sort it.  I edited my post with an example of why this makes python unhappy.